# Best Way to retrieve data from firebase Firestore, then add to an array so you use the information later

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to design a method where I can retrieve data from firebase and atribute this to the global variables. But so far I haven’t had any success, since Firestore is asynchronous, by the time I need the information Firestore don’t have them anymore. Can someone advise how can I create a method to either store this in information in arrays or to assign to the global variables?

```
class _VehicleDetailsState extends State<VehicleDetails> {
String speed, place;

void displayData() {
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Cars')
    .where('id', isEqualTo: Routes.idCar)
    .get()
    .then((value) {
  value.docs.forEach((result) {
    place = result.data()['place'];
    speed = result.data()['speed'];
   });
  });
}

print(place);
print(speed);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `place` and `speed` to be set before processing the end of the method, you need to wait for Firestore to get the document.

Plus, in your example you put the `print` statements outside the method, I don't know if it's a copy-paste mistake.

Try to change your method for:

```dart
void displayData() async {
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Cars')
    .where('id', isEqualTo: Routes.idCar)
    .get()
    .then((value) {
       value.docs.forEach((result) {
          place = result.data()['place'];
          speed = result.data()['speed'];
       });
    });
  
  print(place);
  print(speed);
}
```

When calling displayData() in a method, it will wait for Firestore to retrieve the document with `id = Routes.idCar` in the `Cars` collection.

Comment: I put the print outside the method, because I wanted to make sure that they received the values, but as soon as the method is finish and I try to access the values through the variables I get null